# How do I replace multiple fields in multiple XML files?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, xml

I have around 4000 XML files and I need to replace the value of both `<filename>` and `<path>` fields.
I need to replace those fields dynamically. e.g. `images0001.xml` should have `images0001` inside the two fields, `images0002.xml` should have `images0002` inside the two fields, etc.

I've already used this command to rename the files sequentially:

```
rename 's/.+/our $i; sprintf("images%04d.jpg", 1+$i++)/e' *
```

And I also used this command to delete the `.jpg` extension that was in the two fields I'm trying to change:

```
sed -i 's/.jpg//g' Annotations/*
```

Here is the current state of the contents of the XML files:

```xml
<annotation>
    <folder></folder>
    <filename>1608644703_2.rf.fa179c1e6c47d72d668ac3d83c7f79d1</filename>
    <path>1608644703_2.rf.fa179c1e6c47d72d668ac3d83c7f79d1</path>
    <source>
        <database>roboflow.ai</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>416</width>
        <height>416</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>megot</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <occluded>0</occluded>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>129</xmin>
            <xmax>292</xmax>
            <ymin>145</ymin>
            <ymax>351</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

And here is how I need the files to be changed:

```xml
<annotation>
    <folder></folder>
    <filename>images0001</filename>
    <path>images0001</path>
    <source>
        <database>roboflow.ai</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>416</width>
        <height>416</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>megot</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <occluded>0</occluded>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>129</xmin>
            <xmax>292</xmax>
            <ymin>145</ymin>
            <ymax>351</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

I'm looking for a way to do this in command line, but I can't figure out a solution after searching for a while!

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need an XML tool(*like [xmlstarlet](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/xmlstarlet.1.html)*) ... so:

```
sudo snap install xmlstarlet
```

In a loop ... so:

```bash
for f in *.xml
    do
    xml ed -L -u "(//annotation/filename)" -v "${f/.xml/}" -u "(//annotation/path)" -v "${f/.xml/}" "$f"
    done
```

Comment: I've installed xmlstarlet and made a script containing the code below but when I try to run it I keep getting the error `line 4: xml: command not found`. Am I missing something ? Thanks for your answer btw !

Comment: Just found out that I just had to replace `xml` by `xmlstarlet` and it worked perfectly !

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it with [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) is by running the following command:

```bash
for f in *.xml; do sed "s|\(<filename>\).*\(</filename>\)|\1${f%.*}\2|; s|\(<path>\).*\(</path>\)|\1${f%.*}\2|" "$f"; done
```

- `for f in *.xml; do ... ; done` is a [basic for loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html) for `.xml` files in your current directory. Each file found is stored in the `f` variable.
- `sed "s|\(<filename>\).*\(</filename>\)|\1${f%.*}\2|; s|\(<path>\).*\(</path>\)|\1${f%.*}\2|" "$f"` is the command that is run for each file found. The command does two similar replacements, one for the `<filename>` field and one for the `<path>` field:

  - `s|\(<filename>\).*\(</filename>\)|\1${f%.*}\2|` matches the text `\(<filename>\).*\(</filename>\)` using [regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) (`.*` means match any character between `<filename>` and `</filename>`). The `\(` and `\)` are not matched but are used to [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) the `<path>` and `</filename>` texts which are then used as replacements. Then the text is [replaced by the first capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `\1` (`<filename>`), the [filename without the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/3140225) `${f%.*}`, and the second capture `\2` (`</filename>`).
  - Similarly for `path`, using it instead of `filename`.

After making sure that the above command works as intended by using it in a copied portion of your files, add the `-i` flag right after `sed` to change the files in place.

Comment: +1 This is a working solution as well … Not XML specific but, “all roads lead to Rome” :-)