# How to use "sed" for replacing xml tag in multiple lines xml content on bash

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, xml

I want to use `sed` to replace the XML tag on `bash`.

Here is the example xml content for testing:

```
<xml-content>
<validation>
<timeout>2880</timeout>
<subject>example</subject>
<required>true</required>
</validation>
</xml-content>
```

I want to replace the tag `validation`:

```
<validation>
<timeout>2880</timeout>
<subject>example</subject>
<required>true</required>
</validation>
```

with the new tag `other-tag`:

```
<other-tag>
<hello/>
<more>false</more>
</other-tag>
```

Here is the final expected result:

```
<xml-content>
<other-tag>
<hello/>
<more>false</more>
</other-tag>
</xml-content>
```

How to do it with a single command line `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed` you can select all lines in a file between two patterns(*including the two lines containing `PAT1` and `PAT2`*) and replace them like so:

```bash
sed '/PAT1/,/PAT2/c \REPLACEMENT' file
```

`REPLACEMENT` is text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.

Notice that if `PAT1` or `PAT2` contain foreword slashes `/` then either each one of them must be escaped with a backslash `\/` or the delimiter must be changed to something other than `/` and in which case you need to escape the first of each delimiter sequence when the `c \` command or any other `sed` command is used e.g. you can change the delimiter to `_` like so:

```bash
sed '\_PAT1_,\_PAT2_c \REPLACEMENT' file
```

So you can do:

```bash
sed '/<validation>/,/<\/validation>/c \<other-tag>\n<hello/>\n<more>false</more>\n</other-tag>' file
```

to edit this:

```
<xml-content>
<validation>
<timeout>2880</timeout>
<subject>example</subject>
<required>true</required>
</validation>
</xml-content>
```

to this:

```
<xml-content>
<other-tag>
<hello/>
<more>false</more>
</other-tag>
</xml-content>
```

Notice that the `sed`s option `-i` is needed if you want to edit the original file in place ... Test without it first then use it with a backup suffix e.g. `-i.back` to save a backup copy of the original file with `.back` extension i.e. `file.back` like so:

```bash
sed -i.back '/PAT1/,/PAT2/c \REPLACEMENT' file
```

Notice as well that there are tools made especially to edit XML files that you can use to update,delete or insert XML elements ... See [How do I replace multiple fields in multiple XML files?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1441934) as an example ... Those tools however might require a rather more complex command script than what is required for`sed` in some use cases like yours ... I understand why you asked for a `sed` solution and would myself prefer `sed` as well over specialized XML tools for such task ... Plus `sed` would be more portable of course.